# How does one share a variable in a PHP class if declared like $var (not $this->var)

Tags: php, class, variables, scope

I know it's better to do things the way it's meant to be, using $this->fname to declare and set variables in a class.... i get that..

but to not make this question long, let's just say I have a function in my class that extracts and parses data in to lots and lots of variables set in this $var=""; manner.

say.. 
    $fname = "Sollenn";
    $age = "20";

I have another function in the same class that i should call later in my code, and this function needs to call those variables the same way

```
$currentName = $fname;
etc..
```

If I try and set the class variables $this->fname properly at the first function, the second function/routine will break..

and i cant GLOBALIZE the $fname, etc variables too.. coz i need the variables to stay in the class

is there any other way to do this?

Comment: "f I try and set the class variables $this->fname properly at the first function, the second function/routine will break.. " What happens exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your first method return the array, and then pass it to the second method when you need to

```
Class Foo
{

     public function first()
     {
          // process that builds an array

          return $array;
     }

     public function second($array)
     {
          // do something with array
     } 
}


$foo = new Foo;

$array = $foo->first();

// other stuff in code

$foo->second($array);
```

Edit: thinking about it, there's no need to store the array outside the class

```
class Bar
{
     protected $array_from_first;

     public function first()
     {
          $this->array_from_first = $array;
     }

     public function second()
     {
          $array = $this->array_from_first;
     }
}
```

Comment: yes that's what im doing at the moment .. i have to store in array and parse in the second function, no need to store it outside, correct.

but the challenge is to use the actual variables created ...the variables are coming from a complicated mysql select query by the way and there's tons of it.. i have a routine for each variable passed (checks, manipulation etc).. 

so for now im using an array tnx.. 

oh and as Colin mentioned, the regular $var declared is swiped clean after the function completes..so maybe there is no way.. hmm..

Comment: @brownchild Surely you can just bundle the vars you need into an array and access them in the second method though? Is there some particular reason you need to access `$var` as opposed to `$array['var']` ? You could always extract  the variables into the scope of the second method, eg. `extract($this->vars_from_first)` if you really need them available without having to access array keys.

Comment: yes and that's what i've been doing at the moment.. 

but right now im in several situations that it would be EASIER for me to access the vars from the first function directly..  it's hard to explain, hehe..


i know at the end of the day i have to figure it in the more proper way, but for now, im just checking if there is a way to do it.. it'll save me a lot of trouble lolz

Answer (score 1):

By just declaring a variable `$var = "value";` you are declaring that variable in the local stack. The stack is wiped out when the function execution completes, and the stack is not accessible from outside of the scope of the function.

You will have to use:

- Instance variable (which you say you cannot, although I'd like to see what happens when you try to use them because I suspect you're just not correctly using the variables here).
- Static class variables (but if you need these variables to be different for each instance of the object this obviously won't work)

Comment: thanks for clarifying the swipe clean part.. i guess unless there's a way i can pass it on to the root space of the class from the function, as in $variable form, i cant reuse them in a class huh? 

In flash (i do flash ActionSCript stuff a lot) i can easily send those to the _parent.variable or _root.variable or even to other objects..

Comment: oh and you are partially right w/ me not using the $variable handling properly.. long story short, it's so much easier to manipulate the $variables in their regular from the 2nd function, form rather than having to point to each.. it messes up my code.. specially the HTML blocks

just to example:
    <a href='$url' target='$targetpage'>$texthere</a>

so much simplier and straight forward..i dont even wana type the $this->url thing for this example. such a hassle lol

but in seriousness, there's a lot of more complicated situation i have like the above, regex replacements etc..